# Converting and comparing python multiindex dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am trying to compare two dataframes, looking for different values between theme. One of the dataframes has multiindex columns containing data necessary for the comparison. Below a sample

```
weight = [1,5,2,4]
price = [2,6,3,5]
item = ['A','B','A','B']
date = ['20-12-2020', '21-12-2020', '20-12-2020', '21-12-2020']

DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':date, 'weight':weight, 'price':price, 'item':item})


tuples = (['A', 'weight'], ['A', 'price'], ['B', 'weight'], ['B', 'price'])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

DF1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = index)

DF1['A','weight'] = [1,2]
DF1['A', 'price'] = [2,3]
DF1['B', 'weight'] = [5,4]
DF1['B', 'price'] = [6,5]
DF1.rename(index={0:'20-12-2020', 1:'21-12-2020'})
```

The aim would be to spot differences in weight and price for a given item and date between DF1 and DF2, but I don't know how to proceed given the multiindex in DF1 which contains also necessary data since it contains the item.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be:

```
DF1[('C','diff weight')] = (DF1[('A','weight')] - DF1[('B','weight')])
DF1[('C','diff price')] = (DF1[('A','price')] - DF1[('B','price')])
```

which is

```
      A            B                 C           
  weight price weight price diff weight diff price
0      1     2      5     6          -4         -4
1      2     3      4     5          -2         -2
```

Alternatively

```
DF1 = DF1['A'] - DF1['B']
DF1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('diff',col) for col in DF1.columns])
```

wich gives

```
    diff      
  weight price
0     -4    -4
1     -2    -2
```